# How to preserve vertical text in 'Fixed-Format' ePubs?

Tags: adobe-indesign, epub, epub3, fixed-format

I'm exporting a textbook as a *Fixed-Format* ePub via *InDesign 2020* but noticed vertical text get exported horizontally instead! Here is an example of what I mean:

[image: incorrect text orientation]

Here's how it should look like:

[image: correct text orientation]

Does anyone know  how I can preserve the text rotation? There are hundreds of examples of this issue in the book. Would there be a 'global' setting/CSS to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have control over the Indesign table styles?

See: https://helpx.adobe.com/in/indesign/using/table-cell-styles.html

If the table regions are styled correctly, you should be able to get the styles exported in the CSS. I haven't worked in the latest Indesign, and EPUB table exports have been patchy in the past. However, if you have custom table styles applied, you can edit the CSS to make it match the source as close as possible.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes I do have access to the InDesign file (and the tables styles therefore). I've never dealt with CSS in InDesign before so don't have a clue what script needs adding!? Would you be able to help me with this perhaps? I'd be so grateful if you can! The other issue is that there are hundreds of tables in the book (with this issue) and editing the style on each wouldn't be possible in the time we have :(

Comment: @Lloyd, when you export the EPUB file, there will be a CSS in it. I meant editing that to get your required look and feel.

Comment: Thanks for that. The only thing is, I don't know what CSS to enter within the Export window? :/

Comment: Check out this SO query and answers. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997631/how-to-display-vertical-text-in-table-headers-with-auto-height-without-text-ov

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll have a read and test a few things out! :)