# Vertical headers in React Table

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I am currently working on creating a table with [React Table](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table)

I would like to have the headers vertically rotated, so they take up less horizontal space on my screen.

The only solutions I came across were setting the header width and height on pixels, but this would make it so that it wouldn't resize with different text lengths.

Would there be a better way to achieve this? Added the following image to give an idea of expected result.

[image: Example of result]

Comment: Please provide what you have already tried in code, so we can help you further.

Comment: Similar type of question has already been asked. You can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997631/how-to-display-vertical-text-in-table-headers-with-auto-height-without-text-ov)

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work using the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997631/how-to-display-vertical-text-in-table-headers-with-auto-height-without-text-ov)!

I applied the verticalTableHeader class to the header and it is still responsive to variable headers.

Thank you!